# pallet module in frame_support_procedural crate

Tags: frame

Im looking into some of the procedural macros used, namely the `#[pallet]` attribute to declare a pallet that is recognised by `construct_runtime!`. However, I cannot find the source code for the pallet module (`mod pallet;` line 30) that implements the functionality in the pallet attribute.

https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/src/frame_support_procedural/lib.rs.html#402-404

Can anyone direct me to the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the entry point you are looking for can be found here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet

You will find basically all of the FRAME macros in the `frame/support/procedural` folder.

```
//! Implementation for pallet attribute macro.
//!
//! General workflow:
//! 1 - parse all pallet attributes:
//!   This step remove all attributes `#[pallet::*]` from the ItemMod and build the `Def` struct
//!   which holds the ItemMod without `#[pallet::*]` and information given by those attributes
//! 2 - expand from the parsed information
//!   This step will modify the ItemMod by adding some derive attributes or phantom data variants
//!   to user defined types. And also crate new types and implement block.

mod expand;
mod parse;

pub use parse::Def;
use syn::spanned::Spanned;

pub fn pallet(
    attr: proc_macro::TokenStream,
    item: proc_macro::TokenStream,
) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    // -- snip --
}
```